# Проблема с оператором "New" в Delphi.

Tags: очередь, delphi

Создаю структуру данных "Очередь". Вот код одного элемента:

```
TNodePointer = ^TNode;
TNode = record
value: TElement;
next: TNodePointer;
end;
```

То есть указатель на запись и запись состоящая из поля и указателя на другую запись.
Вот код реализации добавления элемента:

```
procedure TMyQueue.Enqueue(item: TElement);
var
   temp: TNodePointer;
begin
     New(temp); //Здесь ошибка "missing operator or semicolon"
     temp^.value:= item;
     temp^.next:= nil;
     if IsEmpty then
     begin
          fHead:= temp;
          fTail:= temp;
     end
     else
     begin
          fTail^.next:= temp;
          fTail:= temp;
     end;
end;
```

Не могу понять, в чем дело. Где здесь пропущен оператор? Неделю назад код компилировался. Я даже статейку для новичков написал по поводу очереди. А сегодня сел лабораторную делать, а она не собирается.
Весь код [здесь](http://pastebin.com/YGG6TcRr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведенный вами код компилируется после того как поставил заглушки вместо `TElement`.

Приведенные вами исходники не полные - не приведен модуль `UMyProcess`. Скорее всего ошибка там.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ошибку.